# "Recent Solutions" List with multiple versions of MonoDevelop

Tags: ubuntu, monodevelop

I'm working on Ubuntu 11.04, and am using MonoDevelop 2.4 for my C# and other CLI development. I'm using this version since it's provided in the repos. But I just built MonoDevelop 2.6, mostly to play around with, see what's new, and also 'cause that's the version when I work on Windows.

All around, the two play nice together, but there's one place where they share some data that I'd rather they didn't share - the "Recent Projects" list on the welcome page. Preferrably, I'd like to have 2.4 only show projects used with that version, while 2.6 should show the projects pertaining to it. But as things are right now, any project made or used by 2.4 show up in the list for 2.6 and vice versa.

Does anyone know how to change this? I don't know my way around Ubuntu all that well yet, and I'm not familiar with the innards of MonoDevelop either, so sorry if it's something that should be obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the MonoDevelop 2.6.0.1 source code straight since yestercday, I finally found the necessary code change. I guess I'll put this up for the sake of reference, in case anyone's interested.

It turns out that the "Welcome Page" in MonoDevelop is representd by the `WelcomePage` addin. In turn, the visual side of the addin is represented by the class `MonoDevelop.WelcomePage.WelcomePageView`. In here is a method `GetRecentProjects()` which actually retrieves the list of projects to display.

Through this method, control makes its way down to the `DefaultPath` property in the `RecentFileStorage` class, which gives the location where the recent projects xml is stored by default. It's defined as

```
public static string DefaultPath {
    get {
        return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), ".recently-used");
    }
}
```

The `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` enumerated value represents the current user's personal folder; in my case, it's `/home/ken` Note that no version info is present here. This means that the recent files list will always refer to the file `/home/ken/.recently-used`, regardless of which of version of MonoDevelop you're running. Also, the layout of the file does not accommodate multiple versions, so the only way is to redirect the location of this file. This is easily done, by changing the above property to something like

```
public static string DefaultPath {
    get {
        return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "MonoDevelop2_6", ".recently-used");
    }
}
```

before building.

I personally think that these sorts of things should be separated, and since it's an easy change I'm probably going to push for some versioning information to be added to the path of the `.recently-used` file, or otherwise have it added to the contents of the file.